# Angular component for loop

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to do for loop in my component but for loop is not invoked.
Dont know why it is not looping. I am able to loop  in the html file but not in the component ts file

```
 export class examplecomponet implements OnInit {

   somelist:[];
   somevalue:any;

   ngOnInit() {
      for(let listvalue in  somelist){
        console.log("Checking list value",listvalue)// This is not called       
      }
```

}

```
      getSomeApi() { 
         this._auth.getApi().subscribe(data => {
            this.somevalue = data.text();      
            var v = JSON.parse(this.somevalue)
            this.somelist = v;      
         }
       );
   }
}
   checkLoop() { 
 console.log("Checking list value2",this. somelist.length)// this is 
      undefined
}
```

This is my json response

```
   {
 "Demo":{
 "Sample":"Test",
  },

 "Demo1":{
 "Sample1":"Test1",
  },

 }
```

Comment: `somelist:[];` is `undefined` when the loop runs.

Comment: Because somelist is undefined. Check again what you are doing there. And you are not even calling getSomeApi.

Comment: The value is not null .In html file I am able to loop it.. i have updated my question

Comment: `this._auth.getApi()` is an async calle.  `ngOnInit` is complete before the result of the async call is resolved.

Comment: @Subham please check how ngOnInit works. You run the things in it only once, therefore after you do the for loop, your value is still not defined as it's coming from an async call

Comment: `getSomeApi` is `async` so its undefined whenb you enter for loop and resolves later on showing in html.

Comment: you need to learn how asynchronous operations work.  change detection masks it for you in template but in your component, someList is populated asynchronously, so when you hit your loop, it's still an empty array until after the subscribe function runs.

Comment: All of these comments are brilliant but they are missing something really important, due to the fact that the indent is...well ther isn't any: you're missing a closing `}` to close your `ngOnInit()` after your `for` loop ^^

Answer (score 1):

Change your logic,

```
   ngOnInit() {
      this.getSomeApi();
   }

   getSomeApi() { 
      this._auth.getApi().subscribe(data => {
         this.somevalue = data.text();    
         var s = JSON.parse(this.somevalue)
         this.somelist = v; //and where this "v" come from?
         for(let listvalue in  somelist){
            console.log("Checking list value",listvalue)// This is not called
      }
```

Comment: I have to use the somelist value at some other function. How do I make sure that the somlist value is not undefined while using this value in other function. I have update my question

Answer (score 1):

It is because at the moment you call the loop, the data from getApi() function is not receive so the `somelist` value is not assigned. Try put it in side the subscribe

```
logListValue(){
  for( let listvalue in  this.somelist){
  console.log("Checking list value",listvalue)
  }
}

//Put it in your subscribe

getSomeApi() { 
  this._auth.getApi().subscribe(data => {
    this.somevalue = data.text();
    var s = JSON.parse(this.somevalue)
    this.somelist = v;}
    //Add it here
    this.logListValue()
   );
}
```

Comment: I have to use the somelist value at some other function. How do I make sure that the somlist value is not undefined while using this value in other function. I have update my question